# AutoCAD VBA: Selecting objects

Tags: vba, autocad

I have a 3D model of an intricate chimney which is essentially a cylindrical tube with decorative features. I'd like to write a VBA script which find the section properties at several points along its length but I'm not really sure how to do it.

From online searches, I've managed to write a code which puts in a section at a point which I can then run MASSPROP on but I'm not quite sure how to finish it off... I think I'm only one line of code away. I just need to select the section that I've just created.

My almost complete code is below with a comment on the line that I need help with.

```
Public Sub Section()
Dim SolidObject As Acad3DSolid
Dim NewRegionObject As AcadRegion
Dim PlaneOrigin As Variant
Dim PlaneXaxisPoint As Variant
Dim PlaneYaxisPoint As Variant
Dim PickedPoint As Variant
On Error Resume Next
With ThisDrawing.Utility
.GetEntity SolidObject, PickedPoint, vbCr & "Select solid to cut."
If Err Then
    MsgBox "Selected solid must be a 3DSolid"
    Exit Sub
End If
PlaneOrigin = .GetPoint(PickedPoint, vbCr & "Select point to define origin.")
PlaneXaxisPoint = .GetPoint(PickedPoint, vbCr & "Select point to define x-axis.")
PlaneYaxisPoint = .GetPoint(PickedPoint, vbCr & "Select point to define y-axis.")
Set NewRegionObject = SolidObject.SectionSolid(PlaneOrigin, PlaneXaxisPoint, PlaneYaxisPoint)
End With
ThisDrawing.SendCommand ("qaflags" & vbCr & "2" & vbCr) 'This is needed for the operation
ThisDrawing.SendCommand ("massprop" & vbCr)
'How do I select my NewRegionObject???
ThisDrawing.SendCommand (vbCr & vbCr & "y" & vbCr & vbCr & "y" & vbCr)
End Sub
```

If I can get this code to run MASSPROP with my newly created section fine I should be able to adapt it to do the process automatically at several points along the chimney so I think I'm only one line of code off.

Thanks for your help,
Tom

Comment: You really should be indenting your code. `Sub...End Sub` is a block. `With...End With` is another - not just `If...End If`!

Comment: Hopefully the [API](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2016/ENU/?guid=GUID-DFE47717-F7AF-443B-AD78-4E0BB60121C7) will help you, but you don't get an object returned from .sendCommand so either try rewriting it with a function that does or 'find' the region object through whatever means you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'd better exploit Autocad Object Model:

```
Dim minPoint As Variant, maxPoint As Variant
Set NewRegionObject = SolidObject.SectionSolid(PlaneOrigin, PlaneXaxisPoint, PlaneYaxisPoint)
With NewRegionObject
    MsgBox "Area: " & .Area
    MsgBox "Perimeter: " & .Perimeter

    .GetBoundingBox minPoint, maxPoint
    MsgBox "Min Point coordinates: (" & minPoint(0) & "," & minPoint(1) & "," & minPoint(2) & ")"
    MsgBox "Max Point coordinates: (" & maxPoint(0) & "," & maxPoint(1) & "," & maxPoint(2) & ")"
    MsgBox "Centroid coordinates: (" & .Centroid(0) & "," & .Centroid(1) & ")"
    MsgBox "Moments of Inertia: (" & .MomentOfInertia(0) & "," & .MomentOfInertia(1) & "," & .MomentOfInertia(2) & ")"
    '.. and so on
End With
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help!

The code works well now but I'm struggling to adapt it to work from Excel VBA. I tried replacing 'ThisDrawing' with 'ACAD.ActiveDocument' but it doesn't seem to be working.  I've edited my original post to show my new code.

Comment: You are welcome. Please be informed that changing a question after receiving solution to the _original_ one leads to what's been called "chamaleon" questions, which are not allowed here. So, resume your question _original_ version and if my answer solved it then please mark it as accepted. While you may want to make a new post for your new issue. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this, it should be fine now